# Numbering equations in any Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I have to label the equations in one of my answer but I can't find way
to do so.

How does one number equations and tables while writing an answer on a Stack Exchange site?

(I just want to use it on Physics.SE but I am guessing probably it is possible on every site.)

Comment: An example would have been much appreciated.

Comment: **Any** Stack Exchange site does not have a single answer as MathJax is only enabled on specific sites that require it (Physics, Math, etc).  It is not enabled on Stack Overflow however.

Comment: @hjpotter92 say I have some equation which I needed to refer to in order to explain things correctly. In latex one simply uses \label and \ref to refer to equation (or anything in general), but with mathjax (on physics.SE) it does not work. I can you use \tag but again I can not refer I have to manually write the number. Although it is not so important but I think I would still like to know if there is a way to simply copy latex code and have it working with not much trouble.

Answer (score 9):

After checking [editing-help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page on Physics site, I noticed that it also [uses MathJAX](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) for equations etc. similar to what [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) has. You can go through a quick reference guide for MathJAX available on [Meta Mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/27741).

To directly answer your question, you can [use `\tag{}`](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11491/27741).

Comment: Nice job!  Thank you so much.  It worked perfectly for me!!