# Is it possible to have automatic numbering on equations in math-based Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, latex

The `\tag{}` syntax is used to number equations. This however leaves to the writer the job of correctly ordering the labels, which can be annoying when some equation is added/removed in the middle of a text with a discrete number of other numbered equations.

Is there a way to have the equations be automatically numbered incrementally, like what happens in Latex when using the `equation` envinronment?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208770/276202

Comment: If this isn't possible through [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), then it's likely not possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality [already exists in MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=equationnumbers#automatic-equation-numbering). To enable it on an SE site, one would need to include either

```
equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" }
```

or

```
equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "all" }
```

in the `TeX` part of MathJax configuration options.  I think the second option would be too aggressive: it would automatically number all displayed formulas in all posts on the site, which would often go against the intent of authors who created some equation numbers manually.

The first option is reasonable: it would apply only to the displayed equations entered as AMS-LaTeX environments, e.g.

```
\begin{equation}
y=x^2 
\end{equation}
```

There aren't that many of those.

The MathJax configuration (delimiters, add-ons) can differ from one site to another. Perhaps some sites would like to have automatic numbering and others wouldn't.  I recommend opening the discussion on the meta of a site where you'd like to see this changed.